# SharePoint 2010 with Office 2013 Clients

Tags: office-integration

Can someone tell me if users with Office 2013 installed will have compatibility issues with SharePoint 2010 (Publishing site)? Or can someone point me to a source of information on this specifically? (no success with Google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a few compatibility issues surrounding Visio, Project client, and Excel/PowerPivot.  For example:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2755126
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chhopkin/archive/2013/02/14/working-with-visio-2013-files-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Project client 2013 is not compatible with Project Server 2010.